# @Indexed annotation on nested class field not working

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing

I have the following object structure:

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private Contact info;
}
```

and here is the Contact pojo:

```
public class Contact {
    private String mail;
}
```

I want to index on mail field inside Contact. I know I can define Compound Index on User class

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "mail", def = "{'info.mail': 1}")
```

But can I define this index in Contact class somehow using @Indexed annotation or some other way.
If I add @Document to Contact class, it creates a separate collection of Contact which I don't want. I want to store all information inside User collection only and define mail index in Contact class.